# Pygame Black Box

Tags: python, pygame

Code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
```

What happens:
The pygame screen pulls up, but there is a black box covering the top right-hand corner of the screen. I would post a picture but stack overflow wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so what are you trying to make happen?

`pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))` should make that box full screen. Is that your objective?

Comment: This should be a comment and not the answer.

Comment: I agree completely. I don't have enough reputation to make it a comment.

Comment: I can only comment my own posts, I'm a new user

Comment: And what, leave this person hanging? I could help them. It's been unanswered for three days...

Comment: May be many can help him. But without a proper question its difficult to answer. Also, the OP has not edited his own question in 3 days which means either he got the solution already or he doesn't care. If he doesn't cares, they why would any one else care. Period.

Comment: OOOOH SHREKT!... But I agree with the "answer"